# How can I run this gensim code? Do I need some text files?

Tags: python, gensim

I was going through this website yesterday (http://rutumulkar.com/blog/2015/word2vec/)  and the author made use of the file `text8-queen`. In his script I noticed that she did not specify the location of the file and I was wondering how was he able to run it? I am unable to run it? Is there a way to run this file? Thank you.

The script is as follows:

```
import gensim.models
import time
time1 = time.time()

import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)


modelbase = gensim.models.Word2Vec()
sentences2 = gensim.models.word2vec.Sentences("text8-queen")
modelbase.build_vocab(sentences2)
modelbase.train(sentences2)
modelbase.save_word2vec_format("wordvectors/model-text8-queen-only")
modelbase.accuracy("questions-words.txt")

model = gensim.models.Word2Vec()
sentences = gensim.models.word2vec.Sentences("text8-rest")
model.build_vocab(sentences)
model.train(sentences)
model.save_word2vec_format("model-text8-rest")
model.accuracy("questions-words.txt")

sentences2 = gensim.models.word2vec.Sentences("text8-queen")
model.update_vocab(sentences2)
model.train(sentences2)
model.save_word2vec_format("wordvectors/model-text8-queen")
model.accuracy("questions-words.txt")

model1 = gensim.models.Word2Vec()
sentences = gensim.models.word2vec.Sentences("text8-all")
model1.build_vocab(sentences)
model1.train(sentences)
model1.save_word2vec_format("wordvectors/model-text8-all")
model1.accuracy("questions-words.txt")
print ("total time: %s" % (time.time() - time1))
```

My question is in the in the line:

```
sentences = gensim.models.word2vec.Sentences("text8-rest")
```

how did the author call `text8-rest` and `text8-queen`? where should I put these text file (`text8-rest`, `text8-queen`) ? Do I have to specify the location of the text file or is python able to detect it?

Comment: please add the `gensim` tag to the question as it is relevant to the question

Comment: I would assume that it opens the file the same way `open()` does which looks for the file in the working directory, which is usually the same folder as the `.py` file.

Comment: Please edit your post to have a useful title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you carefully read that tutorial, it says

> NOTE: text8-rest, and text8-queen, and text8-all can be downloaded here: http://rutumulkar.com/data/onlinew2v/text8-files.zip.

Comment: download link is dead now.

Comment: @Om, Okay, I'm not the owner of that website.